# JavaScript: Variable Value gets lost between functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, each

I have the following code

```
function updateSliderContent(json) {  //<- json defined here is correct
   var screen_order = json.screen_order.split('_');
   jQuery.each(screen_order, function(i, item) {
      var screen_id = item;
      //at this point it is not, thus the function does not execute whatever is in the if blocks
      if (json[screen_id].action == 'add') {
         //doSomething  
      } else if (json[screen_id].action == 'remove') {
         //doSomthingElse
      };
   }
}
```

My problem is that somehow, the value of json (which is an object from an AJAX Call) gets lost in the each function of jquery. I have not yet found out why, nor how to solve it. Google does not give me the answer I am looking for.

#### Edit 1

Here is the actual call.

```
function updateSlider() {
   var screenOrder = '';
   jQuery('div#slider td').each(function(i, item) {
      screenOrder += this.abbr + '_';
   })
   var ajaxData = {
      sid: sid,
      story: story,
      date: theDate,
      screenOrder: screenOrder,
      mode: 'ajax_update_slider'
   };
   jQuery.ajax({
      data: ajaxData,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (json) {
         updateSliderContent(json);
      }
   });
   theDate = Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000.0); //UNIX Timestamp
   sliderTimer = setTimeout('updateSlider();',15000);
};
```

Comment: You need to provide the containing code if you want an explanation of what is happening

Comment: may be your json is indeed empty, or is it really in the global scope, meaning the XHR call return value is kept in window.json?

Comment: I have changed this to a JS native for loop which seems to solve the problem. Still, I am curious why this happens. Seems like all that praise about jQuery.each isn't all that good (I am still trying to find and learn best practices).

Comment: added the place where json is defined

Comment: Are you sure the loop executes at all? Is screen_order an empty array?

Comment: Yes, it is executed. At this point, json is undefined according to firebug.

Comment: I think Murali VP isn't that far off with his comment. json is a local variable and not defined in the global scope. It is only know to this function an to the function where the latter was called. What the real Question should be: How can I give jQuery.each an additional value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've attempted, and failed, to reproduce your problem on JS Bin:
http://jsbin.com/ereha (editable via http://jsbin.com/ereha/edit)

The code you've shown us so far seems perfectly fine, so the problem must be caused by some other part of your code or system. We're all just shooting in the dark if we don't know what the issue is.

Please try and reproduce the problem on http://jsbin.com and we can help you from there.

### Complete Source Code

#### index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831384/javascript-variable-value-gets-lost-between-functions</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/1.2/firebug-lite-compressed.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $.ajaxSetup({url: 'test.json'});

      function updateSliderContent(json) {  //<- json defined here is correct
        var screen_order = json.screen_order.split('_');
        jQuery.each(screen_order, function(i, item) {
          var screen_id = item;
          //at this point it is not, thus the function does not execute whatever is in the if blocks
          if (json[screen_id].action == 'add') {
            console.log(screen_id, 'action add');
          } else if (json[screen_id].action == 'remove') {
            console.log(screen_id, 'action remove');
          };
        });
      }

      function updateSlider() {
        var ajaxData = {};
        jQuery.ajax({
          data: ajaxData,
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function (json) {
            updateSliderContent(json);
          }
        });
        // theDate = Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000.0); //UNIX Timestamp
        sliderTimer = setTimeout('updateSlider();',15000);
      };

      $(updateSlider);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### test.json

```
{
  'screen_order': 'foo_bar_baz',
  'foo': {
    'action': 'add'
  },
  'bar': {
    'action': 'add'
  },
  'baz': {
    'action': 'remove'
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried to also reproduce the problem on my local server but couldn't... Even if I revert to the version I had my problems with I cannot seem to reproduce it. I'll give you a correct answer for your trouble... still, I cannot understand why it works now...

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be nothing wrong with the jQuery.each as I can't reproduce your problem.

```
        function alertName (json) {
            var a = new Array();
            a.push(1);
            a.push(2);

            jQuery.each(a, function(i, item) {
                alert(json[0].name);
                alert(json[1].name);
            });
        }

        var andre = { name: "André" }
        var joana = { name: "Joana" }

        var arrayOfJson = new Array();
        arrayOfJson.push(andre);
        arrayOfJson.push(joana);

        alertName(arrayOfJson);
```

`alertName()` function works exactly as it should. The json parameter isn't lost within `jQuery.each` function

It seems to be a problem on your implementation, something you're not telling us about. Please try to "compress" your issue to a working sample as I did and show us so that we can try in on our own :)

Comment: That's odd, because this is basically what I am trying to do with the object. The function I provided is actually almost the entire thing. What I removed was the actual call, which you simulated in your example, except thatjson is an Object and not an Array.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `json` is an object. Maybe its a json-string? Than you should `eval` it before use.
If you get it via `$.ajax()` call don't forget to add `dataType:'json'` as an option...

Comment: Try this:
  
    function updateSliderContent(json) {
        alert(typeof json); //<-- here you get an alert with json type. if its string then you found your error
        jQuery.each(screen_order, function(i, item) {
        ...

Comment: I used dataType and set it to json. I actually have it defined in jQuery.ajaxSetup() since 90% of my calls all expect json as result.

Answer (score 0):

tray in the **if()** clause to use **item.action**, because if the json data is an array of objects, **item** will contain each object, but this is only my assumption

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make sure the function **updateSliderContent** is called after the json response from the server side.

The code below shouldn't work:

```
    var json = {};

    $.getJSON("/url/", {}, function(data){
        json = data;
    });

    //we call our function before the server response
    //and the json will be just blank object
    updateSliderContent ( json );
```

So, please have a look at your code because sometimes we did something like that without intention.

The code below should work and the json object must not be blank if the server really response the correct json.

```
    $.getJSON("/url/", {}, function(json){
        //we call only after the response from server
        updateSliderContent ( json );
    });
```